# android - using video as a resource

Tags: android, video, media-player

Is there a way to run a video while the video is one of my resources (located in /res/raw)?
with audio files its working but when I try to run the video, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance
Amigal

Comment: Perhaps, but unless the video is extremely short this may result in an unacceptably large apk file.  It would be better to download the video from a web server to the sdcard upon application installation.

Comment: Show us the code snippet where you try to run the video.

Comment: The Video is 1.5M. and the total size of the app is ~2M is it a problem?

Comment: the code I use is as follows (works ok with audio file):

Comment: Test = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
Test.seekTo(0);
Test.start();

Comment: Is it possible your video format isn't supported by Android media player?